# Apache velocity backward slash

Tags: regex, apache, velocity

I am not able to replace backward slash in apache velocity. Use case is having list of files with backward slash separation(C:\something\somewhere).

When I use this:

```
#set ($p = $p.replaceAll("\\", "_"))
```

I am getting this errror:

> description: org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException:
>   Lexical error: org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.TokenMgrError:
>   Lexical error at line 36, column 34.  Encountered: "_" (95), after :
>   "\"

Anyone any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#set($test = 'C:\something\somewhere')
$test <br/>

#set ($p = $test.replaceAll("\\", "_"))
After Replace: $p
```

### OUTPUT:

> C:\something\somewhere
>
> After Replace: C:_something_somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with `#set ($p = $p.replaceAll('\\', "_"))`